# How to plot a graph using my C program

Tags: c, system

My problem is that I can't plot a graph from my c program.

When I searched StackOverflow and google, I got this statement:

`system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'C:/Users/Ashfaaq Muhammad Dam/Desktop/New folder (3)/myfile.txt'\"");`

But the problem is that the terminal says `Gnuplot is not recognised as internal or external command.`

**//start of the program**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>\
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{       
        int j;   
        int i;  

printf("Enter how many coordinates you want to input:\n");
scanf("%d", &j);

int x[j];
int y[j];

 for(i=0; i<j; i++)
   {      
       printf("Enter your x and y coordinate:\n");        
       scanf("%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);

   }

   freopen("myfile.txt", "w", stdout);

   for(i=0; i<j; i++)        
   {    
       printf("\n%d %d\n", x[i], y[i]);

   }
system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'C:/Users/Ashfaaq Muhammad Dam/Desktop/New folder (3)/myfile.txt'\"");


system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

**// Ending it.**

Comment: You need to install gnuplot

Comment: did you install `gnuplot`?

Comment: After I run my c program, a txt file is saved.
if I use Gnuplot to plot the coordinate in the txt file, the points are plotted. But I want my program to plot it directly after the user inserted the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

is `gnuplot` found when you run it directly from the terminal prompt?

Either `gnuplot` is not installed or it is not in your PATH.

A simple solution is to find its location with `which gnuplot` or `find / -name gnuplot -type f` and use the absolute path in the `system` string argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Actually I haven't inserted it in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install `gnuplot` in your system. Try

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-nox
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-qt
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```